# How to get user data from Foursquare/Swarm under GDPR?

Tags: gdpr, internet

Is there a way to download all my contributed check-in and reviews data from Foursquare/Swarm?

The [foursquare.com](https://foursquare.com/) doesn't seem to have a way to log in with the old foursquare/swarm credentials.

Isn't the company liable under GDPR to provide a way for users to download their data, as well as request full removal?

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/96983/is-it-legal-appropriate-to-email-a-gdpr-sar-to-the-executive-team-if-that-is-the

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't the company liable under GDPR to provide a way for users to download their data

**No**

Assuming the organisation is covered by the GDPR, they have to provide a method of requesting personal data held, but that doesn’t have to be through a self-initiated download or even that it has to be in a machine readable format.

> as well as request full removal?

Yes, they have to provide a method where you can request removal. However, they are not obliged to remove data if they still have a legitimate interest in it.

Comment: There is no right to an automatism or download, but as far as the format is concerned: "Where the data subject makes the request by electronic means, and unless otherwise requested by the data subject, the information shall be provided in a commonly used electronic form."

Comment: @nvoigt Images are not machine readable, but a commonly used electronic form.

Comment: We seem to have different understanding of the word "machine readable". Images are perfectly "machine readable", their format is standardized. If someone sent back an image of an excel sheet instead of an excel sheet, or a screenshot of sourcecode instead of a text file, I would argue that it is not a "commonly used electronic form".

Comment: @nvoigt so you'd say a photo of the index card that holds your data isn't a valid answer but I have to send you an export of the database? That would be **messy**., esppecially if the database contains hundreds or thousands of entries in dozens of sheets. E.g. "User ID"-sheet, then each forum post associated with that has a user-id and a thread-id... with the header of the threads in a thread-id-list... a simple forum is about 2 dozen database sheets, and would be perfectly machine readable and commonly used, but culled to *just* the user data, the data is useless.

Comment: I am saying you must use a "commonly used form". I am not a judge, but "picture of it" is not a commonly used form for any data except images. I would expect an excel, json, xml or csv export as a commonly used format. Or maybe a pdf if it is still *text*, not "picture of text". Nothing messy about it.